# "Organic groups: Group node" equivalent?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, views

I have several Drupal 6 views that use the "Organic groups: Group node" relationship.  Does anyone know what the equivalent relationship in Drupal 7 is?  Trying to set this up in Drupal 7 and the wording is confusing as I don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one I was looking for (after much trial and error) is "OG membership: Group Node from OG membership"

That relationship seems to be the same as "Organic groups: Group node" in Drupal 6